# Why are my Positioned widgets not showing up outside Stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

I'm trying to use `Stack()` in my `scaffold` but when the blue `container` ends, the rest of the `Positioned` widgets (out of the `Stack` widget) are not visible. Neither is the one in the middle (which is half visible) Like so,

[image: app screenshot]

How can I get these widgets to render in my app? Here's my code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 450,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment(-0.00, -1.00),
                end: Alignment(0, 1),
                colors: [Color(0xFF03A4EC), Color(0xFF0467C5)],
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                 Positioned(),
                 Positioned(),
                 Positioned(),
                 Positioned(
                  left: 20,
                  top: 378,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 171,
                    width: 350,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xFFFDFDFD),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      shadows: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0x26000000),
                          blurRadius: 20,
                          offset: Offset(0, -1),
                          spreadRadius: -7,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Column(),
                 ),
                ),
               ],
              ),
             ],
            Positioned(
              left: 20,
              top: 684,
              child: Container(
                width: 335,
                height: 298,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFFDFDFD),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(width: 0.50, color: Color(0xFFEFEFEF)),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
            ),
            child:Container(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default  `clipBehavior` of the stack is
`this.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,`

You can use `Clip.none,` to make widgets visible outside the Stack area.

```
Stack(
   clipBehavior: Clip.none,
 )
```

Comment: Yeah that works. I just have to bring the middle one out of the Stack too.

Comment: + you can use LayoutBuilder instead of hard-coded value